# crypto returning wrong Hex HASH value on react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Reactjs app rendered by Nextjs.

I am trying to figure why i am getting different hash value in web browser when i do this :

crypto.createHash('sha256').update("12345678").digest("hex");

The hash expected using [sha256 online tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html)

ef797c8118f02dfb649607dd5d3f8c7623048c9c063d532cc95c5ed7a898a64f

and doing this on nodejs

```
const crypto = require ('crypto');

const password = '12345678';

console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest("hex"));
```

i am still geting this hash

ef797c8118f02dfb649607dd5d3f8c7623048c9c063d532cc95c5ed7a898a64f

but on web app i am gettng always

fef3d83e32b4d981b0c0f75206e891268c6aa8bd8db5a315db7bf24168a4be27

i tried to use cryptojs/SHA256 and getting exactly the same problem.

Comment: Its probably due to encoding.

Comment: Could you tell more about encoding? My site is using utf-8 enconding. It shouldn’t be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, wrong coding, i was hashing twice the string in another file from the project.

12345678 hash into:
ef797c8118f02dfb649607dd5d3f8c7623048c9c063d532cc95c5ed7a898a64f and this hash into:
fef3d83e32b4d981b0c0f75206e891268c6aa8bd8db5a315db7bf24168a4be27... tadaaaa.

embarrassing things...